# How to send random position to next activity

Tags: java, android

I am showing random images in gridview using string array urls with picasso in first activity and when I'm clicking on any image in gridview then I want to show that exact random image in next activity. i am using put extra and sending that position like int `r = random.nextInt(array.length);` I'm using that r into gridview put extra as position. but when i m setting that r in imageview its showing another random image not exact.

**This is my  code**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   static Random random;
    private GridView photoGrid;
    private int mPhotoSize, mPhotoSpacing;
static int p;
    // Some items to add to the GRID


static final String[] icons= {
                "https://abhiandroid.com/ui/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/horizontalSpacing-in-Gridview.jpg",
                "http://www.whatsappstatusmessages.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/whatsapp-dp-images-in-english.jpg",
                "http://www.sarkarinaukrisearch.in/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/whatsapp-dp-status-in-english-1-77.jpg",
                "https://www.trueshayari.in/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/Love-Status-DP-for-Couple.jpg",
                "https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-2iawNx83Kpw/XL21pPj0aPI/AAAAAAAAKiE/VRR7pupbWDUj0TNNAKdGH8Baaz_c9IcSgCLcBGAs/s1600/ss.jpg",
                "https://www.trueshayari.in/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/Love-Status-DP-for-Couple.jpg",
                "https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-8us6YRiZEh0/XL21c6ibbXI/AAAAAAAAKh4/eNyjErq7q04YCeWxDPWojYfOoAC8BCodwCLcBGAs/s1600/s.jpg"

        };


GridView gridView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    gridView = findViewById(R.id.albumGrid);

    CustomAdopter customAdopter=new CustomAdopter();

gridView.setAdapter(customAdopter);
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SwipeView.class);
            intent.putExtra("id", p);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


}

private static class CustomAdopter extends BaseAdapter {

     static int p;

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return icons.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.phototem, null);
        ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.cover);
        random = new Random(); // or create a static random field...
        p=  random.nextInt(icons.length);


        Picasso.get().load(icons[p]).placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(imageView);

        return view;
    }

}
```

**Showing Image in this Activity**

```
public class SwipeView extends Activity
{
    int positions;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_swipe_view);

    // get intent data
    Intent i = getIntent();

    // Selected image id
     positions = i.getExtras().getInt("id");

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(technoapps4.goodnightshayariworld.MainActivity.p);
}

private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter
{

     String[] icons =MainActivity.icons ;
     @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return icons.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object)
    {
        return view == ((ImageView) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position)
    {
        Context context = SwipeView.this;
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);


        Picasso.get().load(icons[position]).into(imageView);

         container.addView(imageView, 0);
        return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object)
    {
container.removeView((ImageView) object);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Why is p `static`? Beside that you should not initialize static fields in non static methods.

Comment: One quick way to achieve this without much refactoring is by moving the code that does the randomizing to MainActivity, probably below icons Array.

Comment: now i put random into oncreate instead of custom adopter and the out image and inner image are same but outer images are all same i have 7 different urls but its showing all same image when i click n any image it showing the same in next activity but the problem is outer all images are same

Comment: i tried @Whales but its giving error, can you please send me code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this purpose, you should create an `Interface` and pass the random position though that interface.
And the variable `p` isn't the clicked item position. The value of `p` is changing continuously while the `gridView` is populating items.
**Edit:**
Create an `Interface` like this:

```
public interface ItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(int position);
}
```

Now initialize the `ItemClickListener` instance inside your `CustomAdopter` class using the public setter.

```
public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener clickListener) {
    onItemClickListener = clickListener;
}
```

and finally, add the following code inside the `getview` method to pass your adapter position to the listener.

```
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        onItemClickListener.onItemClick(p);
    }
});
```

Now instead of `GridView`'s `OnItemClickListener()`, use this interface to get the correct position. like this-

```
gridView.setAdapter(customAdopter);
customAdopter.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(int position) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SwipeView.class);
            intent.putExtra("id", position);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Don' t know how to create interface for this

Answer (score 0):

I was going to provide you an alternative to this issue which is to use a recyclerview with gridLayoutManager and create a Custom layout that implements RecyclerView.Adapter....All of this might seem confusing to you I guess, so I quickly create a Unit Test to simulate what your code wants to achieve and below is the result.

```
public class ExampleUnitTest {
    private static String data = null;

    @Test
    public void setParentData(){
        data = "I set You";

        Subclass subclass = new Subclass();
        subclass.getParentData();
    }

    private static class Subclass{
        void getParentData(){
            assertEquals("I set You", data);
        }
    }
}
//Tests passed
```

I will take a minute to explain this, since you have your custom adapter as a subclass of MainActivity, then I believe that the subclass should have access to some values of its parent class.
I am talking about this: `static int p;` so you don't need to create two of that like you created in the subclass also which is the CustomAdopter class.
So below is the modification to your code and I believe it should work as far as the test passed, else, pls let me know so I can take a look again.
This is not really an answer but it's the only way I can share code and explain some things in details.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   static Random random;
    private GridView photoGrid;
    private int mPhotoSize, mPhotoSpacing;
   static int p;
    // Some items to add to the GRID


static final String[] icons= {
                "https://abhiandroid.com/ui/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/horizontalSpacing-in-Gridview.jpg",
                "http://www.whatsappstatusmessages.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/whatsapp-dp-images-in-english.jpg",
                "http://www.sarkarinaukrisearch.in/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/whatsapp-dp-status-in-english-1-77.jpg",
                "https://www.trueshayari.in/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/Love-Status-DP-for-Couple.jpg",
                "https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-2iawNx83Kpw/XL21pPj0aPI/AAAAAAAAKiE/VRR7pupbWDUj0TNNAKdGH8Baaz_c9IcSgCLcBGAs/s1600/ss.jpg",
                "https://www.trueshayari.in/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/Love-Status-DP-for-Couple.jpg",
                "https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-8us6YRiZEh0/XL21c6ibbXI/AAAAAAAAKh4/eNyjErq7q04YCeWxDPWojYfOoAC8BCodwCLcBGAs/s1600/s.jpg"

        };


GridView gridView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    gridView = findViewById(R.id.albumGrid);

    random = new Random(); // or create a static random field...
    p=  random.nextInt(icons.length);

    CustomAdopter customAdopter=new CustomAdopter();

gridView.setAdapter(customAdopter);
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SwipeView.class);
            intent.putExtra("id", p);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


}

private static class CustomAdopter extends BaseAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return icons.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.phototem, null);
        ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.cover);

Picasso.get().load(icons[p]).placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(imageView);

        return view;
    }

}
```